# Paypal Developer/Sandbox new interface: cannot login with test accounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm having problems on sandbox.paypal.com login with my test accounts since they've changed the interface.

I was forced to create a new account on developer.paypal.com (which is now a beta) and import my old test accounts. I've done that but none of the accounts work anymore!

I cannot login the sandbox with my merchant account and purchases aren't working.

Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not pay in paypal sandbox using a test Test Account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318571/can-not-pay-in-paypal-sandbox-using-a-test-test-account)

Answer (score 10):

Once you validate and log in using your PayPal credentials, you can import your individual sandbox profiles. Prior to logging in to a specific sandbox account, you will have to clear your browser cache and cookies. I was having the same issue with both Chrome and Firefox. After clearing cache/cookies, I was able to log into to a sandbox profile without any issues.

If you do not clear C&C, you will receive the following error:

"This Sandbox email address is not available. Please enter another email address."

Thanks,

Comment: What browser and version are you using? Have you tried Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: im using Chrome. I got same problem above.

Comment: I just tested in chrome Version 25.0.1364.160 and was able to reproduce the issue and then resolve it after clearing C&C. PayPal is working on a fix to resolve the issue for everyone. In the meantime, you might want to try upgrading Chrome. If that doesn't work, give Firefox a try.

Comment: its almost successful w/ firefox 19 but got error `Dispatch Error, please check logfile for more information`

Comment: PayPal is working on a fix to address this issue for everyone. I will update this thread as soon as this issue is resolved.

Comment: Hello everyone, this issue should now be resolved. Please let me know if you continue to experience log in issues.

Comment: still we are unable to login with paypal account

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to shoot me an email at the address in my profile and we will figure out what is causing the issue.

Comment: Firefox not working, Chrome no, with IE I can login but it's not working well.

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors? I tested FF, Chrome, and IE and all appear to be working.

Comment: Still not working and it is April 2014 now! I cannot login with any of the accounts I used to test payments. It's clearly not a cache problem.