# Can not pay in paypal sandbox using a test Test Account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Since paypal updated their sandbox, I encounter a lot of problems. I can not simulate a payment using sandbox. Whenever i use an "old test account", created before the update, this error message comes out

> **This Sandbox email address is not available. Please enter another email address.**

I have created a new account and unfortunately it also doesn't work. Same error message comes out.  Below is the details that inputted to create an account.

1. email: "test@test.com"
2. payment bal. : 5000
3. bank verified: yes
4. paymentcard: paypal
5. credit card type: none

**Can anyone tell how to do payment simulation using the  new  paypal sandbox?** I have read all the documenation in x.com, None of them worked. The links redirects me to developers.paypal.com and prompt me to login again and again.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem.  I suspect this is because of the recent changes to the developer site.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I resolved it by:

- loggin out of test site
- clearing browser cache and cookies (I use chrome).
- Logging back into the test site
- Changing the credentials for the submission to the automatically created business account in the new paypal sandbox
- Submitting.

Works as expected now.

Comment: To add: or you can manually remove the cookies for developer.paypal.com. Reason is that cookies from the old developer portal are interfering with the new developer portal. A fix is in the works, but this will resolve the problem for good in the interim.

Comment: I faced the same issue here and do what you've said and it works well.. :)

Comment: That actually worked for me but now I have an error on the transaction "10001" Transaction failed due to internal error gotta love Paypal, makes our life so easy.

Comment: @PayPal_Robert is correct, obviously. All that is needed is clearing the cookies to fix this issue.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest solution is to use an **incognito browser window** for the test customer.

This separates the cookies for the "customer" from the cookies for the "merchant" and the cookies from your real PayPal account, which seems to cause the problem.

**Ctrl-Shift-N** in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

hi i resolved this issue
the main caused of issue is that you are logged in your main account, so just open another browser and test your website with sandbox credential.
note you don't have to login on paypal or developer site

or you can clear all paypal cookie & test without login

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the Sandbox.... you're supposed to be logged in. Common problem I've encountered, just log in to the sandbox - then try the code again.

Comment: Yes I'm already logged in in my paypal account. I know how to test sandbox. I also tried clearing the cache but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

1) Open Developer Tools

2) Resources / Cookies

3) select https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/

4) delete all the keys to the right