# PalPAL sandbox IPN processor rejecting all messages?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I was using the PalPal IPN simulator all day without problems, and at some point I got kicked out and the developer portal got upgrade.

Picking up right where I left off, I'm now receiving IPN messages from the sandbox, but attempts to validate the message return 400 Bad Request.

Now before you go saying "Oh, you just need to do HTTP/1.1 and send the Host:" field, I'm already doing that (and have been for months).

Request body:

POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
   Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   Content-Length: 1008
   Connection: Close

Response body:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
   Date: Sat, 09 Mar 2013 00:07:26 GMT
   Server: Apache
   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
   Set-Cookie:   c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=%7chl7gnTEYtJzNIfLXr3W6GtWjMBrl6ln8aFetxEss8pSDsWPDwv59RMYj7ONKH0013betZW%7cnf1wC_g4C0pER3V0XtOw2969OSDVwC24TgW3akpoK6QHdkz0_7G0YdJ9Cnjz-JKZbESVG0%7c; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Tue, 07-Mar-2023 00:07:26 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.109.11.1362787646017906; path=/; expires=Mon, 02-Mar-43 00:07:26 GMT
   Connection: close
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

It it just me, or is the portal broken?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. The ability to verify IPNs in sandbox is broken at the moment. We're currently working to fix the issue now and I'll be sure to update you once we have an update.

Please let me know if you are experiencing any other issues with the developer/sandbox environment and I'll be sure to follow up.

Comment: It might be worth posting to the status page for the sandbox that it's down:

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/site-status/pp-cri

Comment: Thank you for the update Devin, I've requested the site status be updated as well.

Comment: Cause seems to be an errant 'cmd=' right inside the IPN POST data. This is causing our IPN validation service to return a HTTP 400.  
You could either remove just "&cmd=" from your IPN POST data in the interim, or if you can wait a little bit we'll push out a fix for this to production as soon as possible.

Comment: I've tested this out and Sandbox and received confirmation that this has been resolved as of Monday night. Let me know if you are continuing to receive issues and I'll take a look into this further.